# thingsboard rulechain - filter script node to check if metadata timestamp is greater than server timestamp

Tags: thingsboard

I have created an asset variable with a timestamp attribute (dateTo) and would like to compare this to the current server time.
Ho do I get the server/system time of the Thingsboard. TBEL documentation states that "we have added Date class that you are able to use without the package name" so I should be able to get the server time with:

```
Date
```

Testing in the Test Filter Function doesn't error while using:

```
return Date > metadata.dateTo;
```

But does not assess correctly (changing the value around generates a False result either way).

Answer (score 0):

Each metadata field has a string type, instead of integer as expected. So before comparison you have to convert `metadata.dateTo` to integer:

```
return Date.now() > +metadata.dateTo;
```